# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChange does not invoke didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, google-maps-sdk-ios

I trying to record a path user is taking using GoogleMap SDK. I'm using polyline to draw line on a map to show user the path that is taken. In an attempt to cut down coordinates that is generated and to make line looks clean(instead of looking squiggly), I'm calling startMonitoringSignificantChange of CLLocationManger instead of startUpdatingLocation. However, that does not seem to work. It calls didUpdateLocations method just once when the view is loaded, but after that, it just stops calling. Where am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    }

    extension LocationViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            if status == .AuthorizedAlways {
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
                mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
            }
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if let location = manager.location {

                    path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                        longitude: location.coordinate.longitude))
                    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
                    polyline.strokeWidth = 3
                    polyline.geodesic = true
                    polyline.map = mapView

                    // Save the coordinates to array
                    coordinateArray.append([location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude])



                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How far are you moving when you are expecting updates and not getting them?

Comment: Going to downtown which is like 5km away.

Comment: You should expect an update every 500m of so. Are you keeping your app in the foreground and the device awake?  You haven't enabled background location, so if your app is suspended or the device sleeps you won't get updates.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines of codes after `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

p.s. If your view is holding `locationManager` instance, it may not receive location-updates after your view is un-loaded. You may remove following line as it is useless for significant-location-updates:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
```